# Access Settings when changing shell on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-shell

I have a scenario in which I am replacing the explorer.exe Windows 10 Shell, with an exe of my own. Doing this on Windows 8.1 I have no problems. But when I do it on Windows 10, I cannot access "Settings" anymore. It appears that some Windows 10 functionalities require 'explorer' as shell.

Is there a way to open 'Settings' without having 'explorer' as shell on Windows 10? Do I need to implement a special interface in my exe to be able to do it?

The way I am changing the shell, is by replacing the registry key in Windows, to target my exe.

PS: I already tried keyboard shortcuts, command prompt commands, to no success.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Gave you compared the list of running processes? Maybe Explorer starts a vital WinRT host process?

Comment: Apparently, on my particular device, the solution was to ad a registry key "EnableDesktopModeAutoInvoke" and set it to 1. This fixed my issue on Windows 1607,1703, but not on 1709.